# "Der Computer muss zwei Stunden repariert werden."

Tags: usage, passive

Ich habe meine (ausländischen) Schüler gebeten, passivische Beispielsätze mit Modalverben zu bilden. Ein Beispiel klang komisch für meine Ohren:

> Der Computer muss zwei Stunden repariert werden.

Ich kann es nicht erklären, aber irgendwie stört mich diese Angabe „zwei Stunden“. Ich habe versucht ähnliche Beispiele zu bilden (z.B. *Das Haus muss drei Jahre gebaut werden. / Der Patient muss zwei Stunden operiert werden. / Das Buch muss eine Stunde gelesen werden*.), aber in Kombination mit diesen temporalen Angaben klingen die Sätze seltsam für meine Ohren. Liege ich falsch? Machen diese Sätze für Muttersprachler Sinn?

Comment: Streiche die Zeitangabe und stelle fest, dass ein Zustand beschrieben wird. Dies verträgt sich nicht mit der Zeitangabe, weil diese für den Vorgang der Beseitigung/Änderung des Zustands gilt.

Comment: Sprachlich sind alle Beispiele korrekt. Sie sagen nur etwas aus, was üblicherweise wenig sinnvoll ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grammatikalisch sind alle Beispiele in Ordnung.

Logisch nicht so ganz - einen Computer zwei Stunden lang zu reparieren, macht ihn nicht unbedingt wieder ganz. Die aufgewendete Zeit ist nicht direkt zielführend für den Vorgang.

Die von dir genannte Konstruktion wird gerne für Kochen und Backen benutzt, wo die abgelaufene Zeit wirklich eine direkte Auswirkung hat:

> Das Huhn muss nach der Vorbereitung zwei Stunden in reichlich Salzwasser gekocht werden.

> Der Obstkuchen muss 20 Minuten bei 180° gebacken werden.

Comment: "Die aufgewendete Zeit ist nicht direkt zielführend für den Vorgang." - bei Windows Update und entsprechenden Reparaturfunktionen ulkigerweise doch, so kann man meinen. Auch wenn da natürlich seit Windows 8 (?) das Problem besteht, dass man keinerlei Hinweis mehr bekommt, wie lange es denn noch dauert ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Da gab's mal den Joke "wenn Windows Setup ein Navi wäre" - Mit "Sie haben ihr Ziel erreicht"-> "noch zwei Minuten bis zum Ziel" -> "noch 1 Minute bis zum Ziel", usw.

Comment: Wenn das ein bekannter Fehler ist, der in einer Serie vorkommt und schon oft repariert wurde, kann es durchaus sein, dass man aus der Erfahrung eine derartige Zeitangabe machen kann.

Comment: @userunknown Dan würde man sagen "...er muss repariert werden und das dauert zwei Stunden". Aber niemals so wie im Beispiel.

Comment: @tofro: Nein, die Möglichkeiten des Satzbaus und der Auslassungen im Deutschen sind mannigfaltig. Was andere sagen würden kannst Du nicht festlegen und ganz sicher kann jemand auch sagen "Der Computer muss 2 h repariert werden." Dass Dir andere Formulierungen lieber sind, dagegen hat niemand was. Es ist aber für andere nicht normativ.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn du dein Auto in die Werkstatt bringst und man dir dort sagte, "das muss 2 Stunden repariert werden" würdest du annehmen "Der Altgeselle hat grade zwei Stunden Luft und deswegen müssen zwei Stunden auf der Rechnung stehen". Deswegen sagt das keiner, weil das Ziel normalerweise nicht ist, dass zwei Stunden rumgehen, sondern dass dein Auto wieder ganz ist. Was gängig ist und was nicht, wage ich schon zu beurteilen.

Comment: Das Problem an Deinem Beispiel ist, dass es am Confirmationbias krankt. Ich habe gar nicht behauptet, dass man irgendwas nicht sagt, deswegen kann ein Beispiel, was jemand in einer von Dir dafür zugeschnitten Situation sagt, gar nicht widerlegen, dass es in einer anderen Situation nicht gesagt werden kann. Außerdem hat die Frage gar keine Situation impliziert, sondern nur einen Satz, und jetzt sagst Du ja selbst, dass der Geselle dem Lehrling später im Pausenraum sehr wohl sagen kann: "Der Mercedis muss 2 h repariert werden(, dann kann ich bald selbst einen fahren)."

Comment: Es geht aber natürlich auch "Der Computer muss 2h repariert werden - da sind 37 Schrauben zu lösen, das DIsplay muss vorsichtig erhitzt werden, damit sich der Kleber löst, das Flachbandkabel eingefummelt werden, wir müssen einen Stresstest machen, die Festplatte und der RAM sollen aufgerüstet werden und das Nikotin muss bei dem Kunden von der Platine geputzt werden." Außerdem bleibt die Satzstruktur ja die gleiche, wenn es nur 20 Minuten sind, nicht 2h.

Answer (score -2):

Der Satz klingt wirklich merkwürdig. Schlimmer ist jedoch, dass die Aussage

Der Computer muss zwei Stunden repariert werden.

nicht eindeutig ist. Die naheliegende Interpretation ist

> Der Computer muss zwei Stunden lang repariert werden.

Das ist eine *Prognose* über die zu erwartende Zeitdauer der Reparatur. Es könnte aber auch

> Der Computer muss binnen zwei Stunden repariert werden

gemeint sein. Das ist dann eine *Anforderung* im Sinne eines SLA ([Service Level Agreement](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-Level-Agreement)).

Dasselbe gilt auch für die anderen Beispiele in der Frage. M.E. sollte den Schüler:innen beigebracht werden, sich präzise auszudrücken:

> Die Reparatur des Computers wird voraussichtlich zwei Stunden dauern.

> Die Bauzeit des Hause wird drei Jahre betragen.

> Ihr habt eine Stunde Zeit, den Text zu lesen.

Comment: Ich würde "der Computer muß zwei Stunden repariert werden" niemals nicht als "binnen zwei Stunden" im Sinne eines SLA verstehen.

Comment: *Die Reparatur des Computers wird [voraussichtlich] zwei Stunden dauern.* klingt in meinen Ohren wie eine sehr gute idiomatische Alternative mit der vermutlich selben intendierten Bedeutung.